# Transforming a Map with the use of Typecasts to save in Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a map within my client that I want to save into cloud Firestore.

To do this, I have to map it to a `Map<String,dynamic>` type otherwise I will be getting errors due to Firestore rules.

I have already written a map method but it is too wordy.

```
Map<String, dynamic> transformClassAMapToFirestoreMap(
      Map<String, ClassA> myMap) {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {};
    myMap.forEach((key, value) {
      map[key] = value.toMap();
    });
    return map;
  }
```

I know that there is a  method `Map.from()` that transforms a map to a map of other type and is a one-liner. Unfortunately, I do not know how to use this in my case.

What I have is a `Map<String, ClassA> myMap;` and I implement it like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
 return {
  'myMap': Map<String, dynamic>.from(myMap);
 }
}
```

Unfortunately I am getting the following error:

```
I/flutter ( 7669): Invalid argument: Instance of 'ClassA'
E/flutter ( 7669): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'ClassA'
```

Comment: you need to serialize your ClassA

Comment: @YauhenSampir I do have a toMap / toJson for ClassA but how to implement this as a whole?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:

```
Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>>.from(myMap?.map((key,value) => MapEntry(key, ClassA.toJson())))
```

and the `toJson` returns a `Map<String, dynamic>` in which I serialize all my properties.